# How do an HGETALL using redisson

Tags: java, redis, redisson

I'm having difficulties figuring out how to access map keys using the redisson redis library. I want to be able to (with redisson) access keys that are created by a system that is not using redisson. Say I use `redis-cli`...

```
sasus:16379> hset user fname "Nancy"
(integer) 1
sasus:16379> hset user lname "Schmancy"
(integer) 1
sasus:16379> hset user email "nanc@example.org"
(integer) 1
sasus:16379> hset user system "none"
(integer) 1
sasus:16379> hgetall user
1) "fname"
2) "Nancy"
3) "lname"
4) "Schmancy"
5) "email"
6) "nanc@example.org"
7) "system"
8) "none"
```

Now a simple java method to retrieve...

```
public static void getNancy() {
    Config config = new Config();
    config.useSingleServer().setAddress("redis://sasus:16379");
    RedissonClient redisson = Redisson.create(config);
    RMap user = redisson.getMap("user");
    System.out.println("user: " + user);
    redisson.shutdown();
}
```

This throws a `JacksonParseException`...

```
Unrecognized token 'fname': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or Nan
```

...on the call to `getMap("user")`

I see some discussion of Codecs but it's not clear to me if that is the solution. Can someone point me in the right direction? This seems like it should be a common use case.

Comment: Ugh! My question got mangled. Can someone edit it to read "How do I do an HGETALL using redisson?"

Answer (score 0):

The exception is telling you that the data Redisson has retrieved is NOT a valid JSON formatted string. You can either change the data format or use StringCodec instead of a JSON based codec.

Comment: It can't be the `StringCodec`. That just returns the `toString()` value of the `Map` object (e.g. `org.redisson.RedissonMap@67fe2a5a`). Is there another codec I should use?

Comment: I am afraid that's exactly what you code is trying to do: To print the reference value of the `Map` object. If you want to show the content of a Map, try iterate through it and then print the key/value, or use one of the readAll methods.